# Symfony and doctrine issues

Tags: php, symfony

I did not use the sudo when installing doctrine in symfony
So this is what i got..

```
The "https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
to fix that i did this curl -XGET https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json
```

and then i installed composer require symfony/orm-pack composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle

The problem is that it wont add any db config in the env file....
and when i do the `composer require doctrine`
i get this

```
Pontuss-MacBook-Air:cauldron_overflow Pontus$ composer require doctrine
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/orm-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
Nothing to install or update
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Generating autoload files
34 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use thecomposer fundcommand to find out more!
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
Executing script security-checker security:check [OK]
```

So why wont it add the correct data to my env files?
Please any advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony and doctrint not installing correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079780/symfony-and-doctrint-not-installing-correct)

Comment: What's your exact question? If you installed `symfony/orm-pack`, you have already installed Doctrine - there is no need to require it a second time

Answer (score 0):

When you install a recipe it installs some sample data to your `.env.dist` file.

This is only for the first run when you install the recipe. After the install you can do what you want and remove that variables and use it from your Docker for example. So perhaps i don't understood your problem because you wrote that you don't want db config in your env file and in the last line you write that it won't add it.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

I know you use flex but there are some good examples how to use and how to do it. Flex should use the DotEnv-Component.

The last thing is your error (`https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json`). I think you have firewall that blocks the load of the aliases file. So you have to check that first. That call should work if you run it in your browser or with curl. Otherwise it could give a problem to load all components.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing doctrine and reinstall the package :) and now the env file looks like it should :)